# Clear Ionic User from local storage

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Io Users in my ionic application.

In my application, if a user download the app to a device, he will login using different users at times. So need to change the saved Ionic.User in local storage in all the times.

So I would like to know if there is a way to remove a user from local storage. Something like

Ionic.User.clear()

Reference: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/user-quick-start

Comment: How are you saving your user to localStorage exactly?
Vanilla JavaScript or are you using a module such as angular-local-storage?

Comment: It is saved to the local storage by Ionic.Io as given in the reference link. I used localStorage.removeItem(key); to remove the stuff, but it seems a fix rather solution. I was wondering if anyone can help me to find whether I can clean local storage elements stored by Ionic.Io, in a cleaner way. Or more recommended way by Ionic itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local store save it's value in keyValue pair. You can remove your key from local storage :

```
 function (key) {
         localStorage.removeItem(key);
   }
```

Reference link :
[Storage reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)

Comment: Thanks. I too used this solution to remove the KeyValue pair. I was wondering if anyone can help me to find whether I can clean local storage elements stored by Ionic.Io, in a cleaner way. Or more recommended way by Ionic itself.